# Error when importing pyrfc - symbol not found in flat namespace '_RfcAppendNewRow'

Tags: macos, python-3.10, pyrfc

I have a problem using the pyrfc (2.5.0) library to collect data from SAP.
I installed this library via pycharm and also manually with pip and in both cases the **installation is successful**.

**Problem** arises when **importing** the libraby:
dlopen(/.../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrfc/pyrfc.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_RfcAppendNewRow'

I use a MacBook Pro M1, Python 3.10 (as you can see) and also tried to use pynwrfc but nothing worked. Any ideas?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyRFC is not supported on ARM platform, more info in: https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC/issues/278